# Non-negative r.v. $X_n$, with $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability and $E[X_n]\rightarrow 2$. Prove that $\lim_nE[|X_n-1|]$ exists and find the limit.

Tags: probability

Someone posted the following interesting question in this morning. Unfortunately, it was deleted. Now, I re-post it and submit a full solution.

Question: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $(X_{n})_{n}$
be a sequence of non-negative random variables. Suppose that $X_{n}\rightarrow0$
in probability and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[X_{n}\right]=2$.
Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[|X_{n}-1|\right]$ exists
and find the limit.

Answer (score 4):

It is much simpler. by DCT $E(1-X_n)^{+} \to 1$. (The dominating random variable is the constant $1$. Note that DCT is valid with convergence in probability in place of almost sure convergence). 
Now $E(1-X_n) \to 1-2=-1$. Combining these two we get $E(1-X_n)^{-} \to 2$. Hence $E|1-X_n|=E(1-X_n)^{+}+E(1-X_n)^{-} \to 3$.

Answer (score -1):

Intuitive idea: We can imagine that $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in some
sense such that $X=a=+\infty$ on a set $A$ with infinitesimal measure
$b$ and $X=0$ on $A^{c}$. Here, $ab=2$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|X-1|\,dP & = & \int_{A}|X-1|dP+\int_{A^{c}}|X-1|dP\\
 & = & \int_{A}(a-1)dP+\int_{A^{c}}1dP\\
 & = & (a-1)b+(1-b)\\
 & = & ab+1-2b\\
 & = & 3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, we guess that the limit is $3$. In the following, we make
everything precise and prove rigorously.

Formal Proof: Let $\alpha_{n}=E\left[|X_{n}-1|\right]$. It is well-known
that $\alpha_{n}\rightarrow3$ iff every subsequence of $(\alpha_{n})$
has a subsequence that converges to $3$. Let $(\alpha_{n_{k}})_{k}$
be an arbitrary subsequence of $(\alpha_{n})$. If we write $\beta_{k}=\alpha_{n_{k}}$
and $Y_{k}=X_{n_{k}}$, we note that $Y_{k}\rightarrow0$ in probability
and $E\left[Y_{k}\right]\rightarrow2$. Now, we have a sequence $(Y_{k})$
such that $Y_{k}\rightarrow0$ in probability and $E\left[Y_{k}\right]\rightarrow2$
and we just need to show that $(\beta_{k})$ has a **subsequence**
converging to 3. To save symbols, without loss of generality, we
do not introduce extra notation $Y_{k}$ and $\beta_{k}$. Instead,
we prove that $(\alpha_{n})$ has a subsequence that converges to
$3$.

Choose integers $n_{1}<n_{2}<n_{3}<\ldots$ such that for each $k$,
$P\left(\left[X_{n_{k}}\geq\frac{1}{k}\right]\right)\leq\frac{1}{k}.$
Denote $Y_{k}=X_{n_{k}}$. We assert that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}E\left[|Y_{k}-1|\right]=3$.
For each $k$, let $A_{k}=[Y_{k}\geq\frac{1}{k}]$. Note that on $A_{k}^{c}$,
$|Y_{k}-1|=1-Y_{k}\in[1-\frac{1}{k},1]$. Therefore, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
1 & \geq & \int_{A_{k}^{c}}(1-Y_{k})dP\\
 & \geq & (1-\frac{1}{k})P(A_{k}^{c})\\
 & \geq & (1-\frac{1}{k})(1-\frac{1}{k}).
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $(1-\frac{1}{k})^{2}\leq\int_{A_{k}^{c}}|Y_{k}-1|dP\leq1$.
Letting $k\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{A_{k}^{c}}|Y_{k}-1|dP=1.$

On $A_{k}$, we have $Y_{k}-1\leq|Y_{k}-1|\leq Y_{k}+1$, so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{A_{k}}|Y_{k}-1|dP & \geq & \int_{A_{k}}(Y_{k}-1)dP\\
 & = & \int Y_{k}dP-P(A_{k})-\int_{A_{k}^{c}}Y_{k}dP\\
 & \geq & \int Y_{k}dP-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{A_{k}}|Y_{k}-1|dP & \leq & \int_{A_{k}}(Y_{k}+1)dP\\
 & \leq & \int Y_{k}dP+P(A_{k})\\
 & \leq & \int Y_{k}dP+\frac{1}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\int Y_{k}dP-\frac{2}{k}\leq\int_{A_{k}}|Y_{k}-1|dP\leq\int Y_{k}dP+\frac{1}{k}$.
Letting $k\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{A_{k}}|Y_{k}-1|dP=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int Y_{k}dP=2$.
Finally, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int|Y_{k}-1|dP & = & \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{A_{k}^{c}}|Y_{k}-1|dP+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{A_{k}}|Y_{k}-1|dP\\
 & = & 3.
\end{eqnarray*}